# Is it possible to get Google Analytics working on Download.com listings?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Maybe this is possible, maybe it's not.  All attempts to contact support have been futile.  As far as I can tell it's set up correctly however there are a few errors occurring on the page that may or may not be preventing the tracking code from registering and I thought someone with a better understanding of javascript might see a way it can be mitigated.

Here is the product page: http://download.cnet.com/OpenSync/3000-18511_4-75993164.html

Download.com moderators approve all changes before publishing the listed so as far as I can tell GA code is kosher.

NOTE: The GA tracking code on the page is the snippet I added, not cnet.  Also, I have a Vimeo video on the same page which loads into an iFrame and seems to successfully run its own GA script.  In my understanding, you can have multiple trackers on the same page.

One last note... I've utilized a GA debug tool for Firefox and Chrome both are seeing my Vimeo tracker but not the other one.   Also, I've attempted to place debug stops all over the GA code block and none of them get him so it's possible the script isn't even being called although I'm not sure why.

One last, last note... when looking at the page source on Firefox there seems to be a rogue, orphaned '

' tag directly after my GA script block.  Would that prevent the code from being run?

Comment: Not sure i understand the question? Do you own the site, if so add the code to your webpage and it will work fine.

Comment: No, the site in question is download.com.  Users can create HTML listings to promote software however there is little to no analytics provided to give vendors any information about those visiting and downloading from their page.

So, I added the page to Google Analytics and uploaded the snipped to my page but for some reason GA isn't recognizing the tracker code.

Answer (score 1):

That site is owned by cnet.com they have there own Google Analytics tracking code in there :

```
ga('create', 'UA-29362404-2', 'cnet.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Any tracking information you try and add is going to get sent to there Google analytics tracking. 
You might be able to add your tracking code but it would have to be added before they call `ga('send', 'pageview');`   which would be hard to manage with out access to the Source code for the website.

That and this is JavaScript you are talking about not HTML. I don't think the site is going to let you add JavaScript.

So basically you cant add Google Analytics tracking to someone else's website.

Comment: No, that is the code that I ADDED to my page, not CNET.  Yes, it's their website, but I ostensibly have full control over the source code on the page - or at least the section of the page I have control over.